# VBScript datediff problem

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Can any explain why I'm getting this datediff problem.

datediff("d", cdate("1/3/2011"), cdate("3/3/2011")) = 59 days

How can this be????

(I'm working with classic asp)

Comment: On a related note, you should consider using the DateSerial function in VBScript.  Depending on the Localization settings on the machine running the script, it could interpret those strings as DD/MM/YYYY and return 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set the LCID (I had this issue when when I had hosting in the U.K. and I am in the U.S)
For U.S. Dates and Currency...
Session.LCID = 1033

For U.K. Dates and Currency...
Session.LCID = 2057

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct answer.  It is counting up UNTIL 3/3/2011, which is 59 days.

http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=1&d1=3&y1=2011&m2=3&d2=3&y2=2011

I guess it's also possible this is a localization problem, and you think it should be calculating between March 1 and March 3.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, is just came to me a couple of seconds ago - ty for your response though.

Comment: Please select the top answer for your question so others know it's closed.